# CSS - how to trim text output?

Tags: css, text, scroll

I have an arbitrary amount of text that will be displayed in a confined space.

How can I trim the output so that whatever is "beyond" the box is not displayed, *or* how can I force the box to create a vertical scroll bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`overflow`](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/) property. You can set the value to `hidden` to hide the data and `scroll` to scroll the data.

```
<div class="text">this is some text that would be very long...</div>

//Hidden
.text
{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px
}
//Scroll    
.text
{
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px
}
```

Answer (score 2):

usually 'overflow: auto' should work if there is a set height/width.  You can force a scroll bar with 'overflow: scroll'.  You can hide anything with 'overflow: hidden;'

The key to overflow with CSS styles is the height and width have to be determined by the browser in order for it to know when to start overflowing.

Answer (score 2):

For HTML:

```html
<div id="smallBoxWithLotsOfText">There is way more text in here than what
    I have typed.  I mean, this text is long.  There is lots of it.  
    You can't even imagine how long this text is gonna get.  No joking.  
    It's long; it's very, very long.  It keeps going, and going, and going. 
    It's the Energizer Bunny of text.  Like, seriously dude.  It's crazy.  
    Absolutely crazy.
</div>
```

Try CSS:

```css
#smallBoxWithLotsOfText {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The height property tells the box how high to be.  The overflow property tells the box to add a scroll bar when the contents get bigger, but not to always have a scrollbar (like `scroll` does).

You can [see this in action](http://jsfiddle.net/d5Faf/1/).

Comment: Ironically, your text wasn't long enough. I had to reduce the size of my window to make the scrollbar appear.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `overflow`. `overflow: hidden` clips content, `overflow:Scroll` adds a scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I trim the output so that
>   whatever is "beyond" the box is not
>   displayed

Use `overflow: hidden`

> How can I force the box to create a
>   vertical scroll bar?

Use `overflow: auto`.  To use this, though, make sure you have a width/height specified on the box

Answer (score 1):

You may try using ellipsis by adding the following in CSS:

```
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

More ways to trim text and show ellipsis can be found here: 
http://blog.sanuker.com/?p=631